# What is the measure, in degrees, of $\angle BFC$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, contest-math, triangles, problem-solving

In triangle ABC, $\angle CAB = 18$ and $ \angle BCA = 24$ .$ E $ is a point on $CA $ such that $\angle CEB=60$ and $F $is a point on $AB $ such that $\angle AEF=60$.What is the
  measure, in degrees, of $\angle BFC$?

Taken from the 2014 IMC

Ive solved similar problems but im not sure how to solve this

I worked out $\angle BAC= 18$ , $\angle EBC =96$ , $\angle FEB = 42$, and $\angle BEC = \angle FEB = \angle AEF=60$.

Comment: I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: Just keep on finding as many angles you can, ultimately you will find the answer. Also as @MichaelRozenberg said, it is an unspoken rule in math stack exchange to tell what have we tried to solve a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D$ be placed on the line $BC$ such that $B$ is placed between $D$ and $C$.

Thus, since $$\measuredangle DBA=42^{\circ}=\measuredangle ABE,$$ we see that $BA$ is a bisector of $\angle DBE$ and since $EF$ is a bisector of $\angle AEB$, we obtain that

$CF$ is a bisector of $\angle BCA.$

Id est, $$\measuredangle BFC=12^{\circ}+18^{\circ}=30^{\circ}.$$

Comment: How did you use the other bisectors to prove CF was also a bisector?

Comment: @Tyrone Since $EF$ is a is a bisector of $\angle AEB,$ we see that distances between $F$ and $AC$ and $BE$ are equal. Also, since $BF$ is a bisector of $\angle DBE$, we see that distances between $F$ and $DC$ and $BE$ are equal. Thus, distances between $F$ and $DC$ and $AC$ are equal, which gives that $CF$ is a bisector of $\angle BCA$.